# Unknown column in 'field list', in db, after a change in field name

Tags: php, mysql, fieldlist

I have a website that uses a database (www.eqtraders.com) It is run with PHP and MySQL

It seems that the host recently updated PHP and now '**yield**' is a `predefined keyword` in PHP.
So... I went everywhere and changed all field reference of yield to r_yield.  I then change the database field names to `r_yield`.

I am confident that the code is sending the following query:

```
INSERT INTO recipes (item_id, r_yield, tradeskill, restriction, triv_low, triv_high, date_added, triv_display) VALUES ("51998", "1", "Spell Research", NULL, "432", "432", "2015:11:04", "432")
```

And for this, I get the error:

> Unknown column 'r_yield' in 'field list', in db: recipes

`PHPMySQL` reports the field names are r_yield (There are two tables other than recipes that also needed to be changed)

[Screenshot of PHPMyAdmin with the name change.  Field 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIVoe.png)

Does anyone have any advice on what I might need to do?

Comment: Try to clear database model cache if any

Comment: not entirely sure why a PHP Keyword would affect an sql query, at the very least you would be using the string value `'yield'` when accessing the data from the query resault

Comment: "It is run with PHP and MySQL" is not so informative. Did your website run on any framework? which version? each framework has its own way dealing with database so please provide that information. Regards,

Comment: It is running PHP Version 5.6.14 and MySQL Version 5.5.46-cll on Apache Version 2.4.17.

Comment: I admit to being a rank amateur, especially when I wrote this code years ago.  It is running PHP Version 5.6.14 and MySQL Version 5.5.46-cll on Apache Version 2.4.17. <br> there is no framework.  It is custom code.  an example of a few lines of code (Much code in between cut out) that was giving an error is `extract($_GET); extract($_POST); extract($_SERVER);


 if (isset($data) && isset($rsdata) && isset($rcdata)) {
  $rs = $data[item_id];

    for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
     $rs_temp_data[item_id] = $rsdata[item_id][$i];
     $rs_temp_data[r_yield] = $rsdata[r_yield][$i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample code, the use of "item_id" and "r_yield" is not very clear, they might either be constants or strings.

The problem lies on the PHP side. I suggest :

- you rename the columns in the MySQL table back to "yield", since that didn't need to be modified in the first place, "yield" being a PHP keyword, not a MySQL keyword.
- you use single quotes in your PHP code for strings :

  ```
  $rs = $data['item_id'];
  $rs_temp_data['item_id'] = $rsdata['item_id'][$i];
  $rs_temp_data['yield'] = $rsdata['yield'][$i];
  ```

Comment: This is finally what I had to do.  Thank you!